# Objects display differently in console and act differently in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The following is a screenshot of two objects in my Chrome console. Both were created by a Javascript function that interacts with a Google Script file. The first was defined with the key-value pair, the second was defined as empty and then had key-value pairs added to it by a for-loop.

[image]

The bottom one appears empty, but is actually not. The info button tells me that it was 'evaluated just now'.

The problem is that I am sending this object to a Google Script function, and when I do that, it comes through as an empty object. Is there any way to force the object into the first form before executing the code that sends it to Google Scripts?

Setting a timeout on the execution of the Google Script call works, but only when the for loop that creates the object has finished in time.

My code looks like this:

```
function logIt(blob) {

  var page_labs = {};

  PDFJS.getDocument({data: blob}).then(function (PDFdoc) {
    for (var i=1; i<=PDFdoc.numPages; i++) {
      PDFdoc.getPage(i).then(function (PDFpage) {

        var page_number = PDFpage.pageIndex + 1;
        var labs = ''

        PDFpage.getTextContent().then(function (text) {
          for (var j in text.items) {
            var item = text.items[j]
            if (item.str.substr(0,1) == '♩') {
              labs += '♩'
            }
          }
          page_labs['Page ' + page_number.toString()] = labs
        })
      })
    }
  })
  console.log({'Page 1': '♩♩♩♩♩♩♩♩♩♩♩♩'})
  console.log(page_labs);
  google.script.run.lofNumbers(page_labs)
}
```

Comment: The function that fills `page_labs` is asynchronous, when you are logging it, the variable is still empty. When the function that fills it has finished, it contains the value. That is why is telling you "evaluated just now".

Comment: I thought Javascript functions ran synchronously? Is there any way to prevent this asynchronous behaviour in this case?

Comment: yes you have to implement your code as it is running with nested callbacks, or you use Promise (that in part you are already using): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Ah, I see promises are the 'then' part of the code above (I copied this from PDF.js examples without knowing how they worked exactly). Thanks

Comment: exactly. They are using promises to run your code when the blob for the pdf has been loaded. You need to use the same idea, but to run the console.log when the page_labs has been filled up by the pdfjs callbacks

Answer (score 0):

**console.log** it by using **JSON.stringify** method,

example:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(page_labs))
```

Comment: I end up with an empty object with no option to expand it in the console!

Comment: try logging it after this statement,

page_labs['Page ' + page_number.toString()] = labs

Comment: I'm going to try implementing a promise first, but I'll also try your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: ok sure, try async-await approach, that'll also solve your problem.
goodluck ;)